# Objective-C : Change @property programmatically (without pre built methods)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to learn how to change an object's property without using the preset methods. This example is just an example. I know there are rebuild methods for this `alertControllerWithTitle...` but I want to do it straight with the property.

```
- (IBAction)clickedButton:(id)sender {
UIAlertController * view=   [UIAlertController
                             alertControllerWithTitle:@"My Title"
                             message:@"Select you Choice"
                             preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                     actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                     {
                         //Do some thing here
                         [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                     }];
UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                         actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                         handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                         {
                             [view dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                         }];

[view addAction:ok];
[view addAction:cancel];
[self presentViewController:view animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I want to update the title `@property (nullable, nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;` How would I do this?

Comment: Since telling you to simply call `view.title = @"New Title";` seems way too obvious you need to clarify your question. What is it you don't understand here?

Answer (score 1):

```
view.title = @"The new title";
```

I feel there is more to your question? It's unclear what you mean by "preset method."

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to learn how to change an object's property without using the preset methods.

All a property really *is* is a promise that certain accessor methods exist, whether they were synthesized by the compiler or provided by the programmer. There may or may not be an actual instance variable used to store the property's value.

It sounds like you're asking how to change the ivar directly, without using the methods. You can certainly do that if you want, provide an ivar exists for the property and you know its name. For synthesized properties, there will be an ivar named the same as the property but prefixed with an underscore, unless the programmer specifies some other name in the property declaration. In other words:

```
@property int foo;     // ivar for foo is named _foo
@property int bar;
//...
@synthesize bar = bar; // ivar for bar is named bar
```

Anyway, if you know the variable name, you can set its value directly or with accessors:

```
[self setFoo:10];
self.foo = 10;
_foo = 10;
```

Those all have the same effect if the `-setFoo:` accessor does the standard thing. However, if the code isn't yours, you can't be sure that `-setFoo:` doesn't do more than just setting the variable `_foo`, so you should use the setter.

In general, it's best to use accessors unless there's a reason not to (such as in an initializer).